# What does the Mars symbol (♂) mean in Chinese (subtitles)?

Tags: meaning

I keep seeing this - probably in some B站 (BiliBili) type of videos:

[image: hehe]

It looks like the Mars Symbol to me:

> ♂

although the orientation is a bit off.

This clearly is not a Chinese character - but what is it doing here?

What does the Mars symbol (♂) mean in Chinese (subtitles)?

Comment: Most meanings of the male symbol is sex related. The male symbol in this subtitle seems mean three F words,  a context may help understand what it exactly mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a long story but TLDR is it indicates that the content being shown has male homosexual connotation (in a humorous way)

The story probably starts with GV actor Billy Herrington's video being uploaded onto a video sharing websites in China (probably B站 or A站). In the video there are a lot of wrestling scenes for some reason and the 弹幕 will say “摔♂跤” with a mars(male) symbol in it to indicate the homosexual element in a funny way, because people generally don't really understand why wrestling scenes would be present in such videos and people start to wonder "what exactly are they doing." They go ahead and push that thought to a philosophical level and start considering that as funny, not comprehensible and humorous.

And then it kinda goes beyond that scope, and anything that can be remotely related to that sense, you can insert ♂ in it to indicate that humorous effect.

Comment: Does it have any kind of 象声? ji1 jī might not be a bad reading for it!

Answer (score 0):

♂ is a 'male' symbol. The one in the subtitles had the arrow pointing up may just be a variant

[image]

Venus symbol represents 'woman'

Mars symbol represents 'man'

Contemporary Chinese people recognize these two symbols too.

The three 'Man' symbols in the subtitles may indicate that person is feeling 'manly'

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question of: what does it mean.

Comment: It means 'male' or 'man'